# React Native: Rendering text from a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my loop I have to get the address of lat and long. I have this function using reverseGeolocation

```
_getLocationAddress = async location => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const { status, data } = await srs.getReverseGeolocation(location);
        if (data) {
          resolve(data.results[0].formatted_address);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  };
```

I also tried not wrapping into promise and not async it doesn't work it keeps returning a promise object. What I need from there is to return the data result into string. Here's my render

```
renderNewSR() {
    const { delivery_items } = this.state;
    return delivery_items.map((prop, key) => {
      const location = {
        latitude: parseFloat(prop.pickuplat),
        longitude: parseFloat(prop.pickuplong)
      };
      //console.log(location);
      const address = "";

      this._getLocationAddress(location)
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
.....
```

What is alternative solution to this. I want the result from google api return as string and can be displayed in render.

Comment: I have posted a solution below. Let me know if that solves your query.

Answer (score 1):

You are not declaring arrow function `async` inside `new Promise` but you are trying to use `await` inside that function.

Just add `async (resolve, reject)` to solve the issue.

Also you don't need to use `async` in `async location` as you are not awaiting any promise but returning promise in wrapper function.

```
_getLocationAddress = async location => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const { status, data } = await srs.getReverseGeolocation(location);
        if (data) {
          resolve(data.results[0].formatted_address);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  };
```

Hope that helps!!!